# How to resolve path in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a user control name "**news**"  which is inside the "**userControl**" folder looks like userControl/news  and code is here

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data" %>

<div id="news">

    <% string getLatestNews = "SELECT * FROM pages WHERE show='True' Order By Date DESC";
       DataSet latestNews = new DataSet();
       latestNews = sage.connectionhandler.ExecuteFetch(getLatestNews);
       int cnt = 1;
       foreach( DataRow dr in latestNews.Tables[0].Rows)
       {

          string NewsId=dr["pageid"].ToString();
           string NewsTitle=dr["Title"].ToString();
           if (NewsTitle.Count() >= 100)
           {
               NewsTitle = NewsTitle.Substring(0, 100);
           }
           cnt=cnt+1;
        %>
    <div class="inside-news" >


        <a id="news1" href='../pages/news.aspx?id=<%=NewsId %>'> 
         <%=NewsTitle %></a>

    </div>
    <% if (cnt >5)
       break;
} %>
```

currently I am here **US/market/commodities/pages/index.aspx**

when I click on the link of each news title in the
**US/market/commodities/pages/index.aspx** page then news link goes to the root of "**US/market/commodities/pages/news.aspx?id=10**" not in the root "**pages/news.aspx?id=10**"

SO how to resolve the above path problem?

Comment: user `Page.ResolveUrl` it solve ur problem

Comment: The Issue is here i guess `href='../pages/news.aspx?id=<%=NewsId %>' ` check the link i guess it would be like `href = '../../pages/news.aspx?id=<%=NewsId %>'`

Comment: do you want like this, yoursitename/pages/news.aspx?id=10 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
string newsLink = Page.ResolveUrl("~//pages/news.aspx?id=") + NewsId;
```

And markup

```
<a href='<%=newsLink %>'><%= NewsTitle %></a>
```